# How to do database schema testing across distinct applications that share the same schema

Tags: spring, microservices, liquibase, datacontract, pact

I have a situation where I have two SpringBoot microservices which share the same database schema.  The schema is maintained by a liquibase changelog file.  One service reads from the database, and the other service is responsible for writing to the database.

Right the Writing Service owns the liquibase changelog file, which means the Writing service owns the schema.  And the way I validate the Reading Service is to deploy the Writing service first into a test environment followed by the Reading Service, and then execute end-to-end tests against the Reading Service.

Is there a way for both services (two separate apps, two separate repos) to share the liquibase changelog file?  I feel this is similar to a contract test as the changelog file will be the contract for both services, but wasn't sure if there was something provided by Liquibase, Spring, Pact, etc that supported this idea.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I think it won't count as a legit answer, but two solutions come to mind:

1. since your second service reads from the database, I suppose you have a full set of entities there, and entities are supposed to match your database schema. And since you're using Spring, I suppose you can add `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` to the `application.properties` file. This will validate your database schema against the entities.
2. You can create a separate library which will contain all the changeLogs. After that you can include this library to both services, so liquibase will validate that all changeSets are executed during application's deployment. But you should make sure that all your changeSets have preConditions, so your deployment won't fail and there won't be any duplicates in the DB schema.